# CMake add_subdirectory not invoking the child CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, makefile, build, cmake

I have a project structure like this which I wish to build using CMake.

```
root\
|
|--crystal\
|        |
|        |--include\ Math.h, Window.h
|        |--src\ Math.cpp, Window.cpp
|        |--lib\
|        |--CMakeLists.txt // the CHILD cmake
|
|--game\ main.cpp
|--CMakeLists.txt // the PARENT cmake
```

The **crystal** sub-project is supposed to produce a static library (`libcrystal.a`) in the `lib/` folder (using the contents of `include/` and `src/`) and the **root** project will produce an executable out of `game/main.cpp` linking the `libcrystal.a` static library.

**The Parent CMAKE is as follows:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)
project(thegame)

set(CRYSTAL_LIB_DIR lib)
set(CRYSTAL_LIB_NAME crystal)

add_subdirectory(${CRYSTAL_LIB_NAME})

set(LINK_DIR ${CRYSTAL_LIB_NAME}/${CRYSTAL_LIB_DIR})

set(SRCS game/main.cpp)
link_directories(${LINK_DIR})
include_directories(${CRYSTAL_LIB_NAME}/include)

add_executable(thegame ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(thegame lib${CRYSTAL_LIB_NAME}.a)
```

**The child CMAKE is as follows:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.1)

project(crystal)

include_directories( include )
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC "src/*.cpp")

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CRYSTAL_LIB_DIR})
add_library(${CRYSTAL_LIB_NAME} STATIC ${SRC})
```

**What isn't working:**

When I executed `cmake .` and `sudo make` in the `root/` directory I expected both parent and child cmake to run sequentially. But it seems like the child cmake is **not getting invoked** and thus not producing the `.a` file. Its showing some error like:

```
Scanning dependencies of target thegame
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/thegame.dir/game/main.cpp.o
[ 40%] Linking CXX executable thegame
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrystal
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/thegame.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'thegame' failed
make[2]: *** [thegame] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/thegame.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/thegame.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**What is working:**

I went ahead the did this

1. executed `cmake .` in `root/`
2. navigate into the `crystal` folder and manually invoked the Makefile by `sudo make`
3. came to the `root/` again and invoked the outer Makefile by `sudo make`

and this **perfectly worked**.

**Question:**

Why the child CMake is not getting invoked as I mentioned in the **What isn't working** section ???

Comment: General advice: Don't do _in-source_ builds (i.e. `cmake .`) with CMake. Create a separate build directory outside the project directory tree (e.g. as a sibling to `root/`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `target_link_libraries(thegame ${CRYSTAL_LIB_NAME})` in the root CMakeLists.txt and remove `link_directories` call. CMake will recognize that you are linking to `crystal` target and set makefile dependencies and compiler flags accordingly.

Comment: That solved my problem. So, the `lib` prefix and `.a` extension wasn't required explicitly. However I was wondering why removing `link_directories` call didn't affect anything. Isn't it required for `g++`'s `-L` switch ?

Comment: @AyanDas CMakes figures that out and adds everything needed. As a rule of thumb just pass full paths to libraries into `target_link_libraries` and don't use `link_directories` altogether.